# Java Application not opening on Ubuntu but opening on windows

Tags: jar, noclassdeffounderror

Hi I have java desktop application developed by myself which uses external jar files. When i open it on windows it opens successfully but on Ubuntu 14.04 it fails with exception.

Windows:

```
java -cp bin;lib\thinlet.jar;lib\xercesImpl.jar;lib\xml-apis.jar;lib\commons-cli-1.0.jar;lib\jsyntaxpane-0.9.5-b29.jar;lib com.macpropeditor.propedit.ApplicationRunner
```

Ubuntu:

```
java -cp bin:lib\thinlet.jar:lib\xercesImpl.jar:lib\xml-apis.jar:lib\commons-cli-1.0.jar:lib\jsyntaxpane-0.9.5-b29.jar:lib com.macpropeditor.propedit.ApplicationRunner
```

On ubuntu I am getting below error:

```
abc@abc-virtual-machine:~/MACPropEditor$ java -cp bin:lib\thinlet.jar:lib\xml-apis.jar:lib\xercesImpl.0.jar:lib\jsyntaxpane-0.9.5-b29.jar:lib com.macpropeditor.propedit.ApplicationRunner
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/cli/ParseException
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2570)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:2813)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1663)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.getMainMethod(LauncherHelper.java:494)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:486)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.cli.ParseException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
```

Is there anything i need to set on Ubuntu? Please suggest. 
All jars present in 'lib' directory.

Java version **windows**:
java version **"1.6.0_27"**
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_27-b07)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 20.2-b06, mixed mode, sharing)

Java version **Ubuntu**:
java version **"1.7.0_65"**
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.5.2) (7u65-2.5.2-3~14.04)
OpenJDK Server VM (build 24.65-b04, mixed mode)

Programm is compliled on windows machine and deployed on ubuntu as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is resolved:

I was using '\' instead of '/' on ubuntu.

So the below cmd is working:

```
java -cp bin:lib/commons-cli-1.0.jar:lib/thinlet.jar:lib/xercesImpl.jar:lib/xml-apis.jar:lib/jsyntaxpane-0.9.5-b29.jar:lib com.macpropeditor.propedit.ApplicationRunner
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm betting it's due to different Java versions. Java on Ubuntu is not recognizing the class(es) because they are compiled using a later version of Java (eg Java 8, but running with Java 7).

Check your java version in both cases using `java -version`.

Comment: @davamac, I have updated the java versions in questions.
Do you want me to build it on ubuntu as well?

Comment: No, the problem would have been that the Java version on Ubuntu was _older_, but you have shown that it is newer. I guess the next step is to verify that the jar files that you list on the classpath are the same on both Windows and Ubuntu (check md5sum or similar). And then try to find which jar file actually contains the not-found class.

Comment: thanks for suggetion. But the jars are same because i just copied them from windows to ubuntu. Also from the exception looks like the problem with commons-cli-1.0.jar-->  NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/cli/ParseException
Do know how to go further  :-(